# Python TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting, while passing parameter to a PostgreSQL query

Tags: python, string, postgresql

I know this question have been asked before but any of the answers was helpful for me, I am using Basic module(psycopg2) in python trying to pass an external parameter **row[1]** into a Postgres Query which is:

```
 print row[1], type(row[1])
```

> 630776863141535744 `<type 'str'>`

when I run the following code I face **TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

```
for row in rows:
   t=row[1]
   PSQL1="SELECT occorrenza.tag from occorrenza where tweet=%s and tag in ( select pk_tag from hashtag where isentity=FALSE);"
   c.execute(PSQL1,t)
```

also I have tried the following code and have the same error :

```
for row in rows:
    c.execute("SELECT occorrenza.tag from occorrenza where tweet=%s and tag in ( select pk_tag from hashtag where isentity=FALSE);",row[1])
```

I have changed many other parts like putting `'%s'`instead of `%s`
but I still have error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `execute()` should be a tuple in your case:

```
for row in rows:
    c.execute("SELECT occorrenza.tag from occorrenza where tweet=%s and tag in ( select pk_tag from hashtag where isentity=FALSE);", (row[1], ))
```

Comment: Also, query should be parametrised with `?`, not with `%s` as in string firmatting.

Comment: @Rogalski nope, `%s` is correct, proof: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries. Thanks.